# XSL Binding error

Tags: xml, xslt, mule

I am using mule to perform some xsl translations

my `input xml` is :

```
<root>
  <Items>
    <Item line="line1"> Item1 </Item>
    <Item line="line2"> Item2 </Item>
    <Item line="line3"> Item3 </Item>
  </Items>
</root>
```

my `xsl` logic is

```
<xsl: for-each select="//root/Items/Item>

  <xsl:element name="test">
       <xsl:value-of select="//@line"/>
  </xsl:element>

</xsl: for-each>
```

I expect my result to be

```
<test>line1</test>
<test>line2</test>
<test>line3</test>
```

but I get

```
 <test>line1 line2 line3</test>
  <test>line1 line2 line3</test>
  <test>line1 line2 line3</test>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am getting the result result the one you expected ... I don't see any issue with the xsl expression .. It should work ...

Comment: Please post a **complete** example of the XSLT stylesheet - especially the wrapping template's `match` pattern. -- Note also that the code you have posted is invalid: there is an extra space in `<xsl: for-each...`, and the closing quote is missing.

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary How did you manage to execute the code - without even knowing the template match?

Comment: Why don't you use `<xsl:value-of select="@line"/>`?

Comment: @MarcusRickert That's a good question: apparently OP is using XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm confused. This is not supposed to mean that `<xsl:value-of select="@line"/>` would not work in XSLT 2.0, is it?

Comment: @MarcusRickert No, but `<xsl:value-of select="//@line"/>` would work **differently** in XSLT 2.0, producing exactly the result OP is complaining about: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHT5 - as opposed to XSLT 1.0: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHT5/1

Comment: @michael.hor257k: OK. Got it. Thanks for explaining. It has been too long a day for XSLT... :-)

Comment: @MathiasMüller : <xsl:template match="/"> works .. so I don't require to know the template

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary I suggest you re-check your result.

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary **1.** I am not Mathias Müller. **2.** "*I suggest you re-check your result*" is a polite way to tell you that you are wrong. Look closer at the result you are getting and compare it to the result requested by the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <xsl:value-of select="//@line"/>
```

selects *every* attribute named `line` in the entire document, regardless of which element the attribute belongs to. If you just want the `line` attribute of the element you are currently looking at in the `for-each` then remove the leading slashes and say simply `select="@line"`.